# CSS - Setting the top/left properties of a rotated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider I have a relative/absolute positioned div with a `transform: rotate` property set on it. How does changing the top/left properties of this div affects its position on the screen? In a small demo that I created, it looks like when trying to move that div, by changing its top/left properties, it won't move as expected. For example, in the demo below, i have a relative positioned div, which is rotated by 45deg, and initially positioned at (300px, 300px). When trying to move this div by (5px, 5px), the div will actually move backwards... Why it that?

Here is the demo - [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DgKLp) (Click the red square in order to move it by 5px in each direction)

Thanks!

Comment: It moves just as expected, top is still top even when rotated, it's just the top of the element, and not neccessarely the top of the window, so it's just not what you seem to expect, but it actually makes perfect sense. Look into tranforming the origin instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `position` attempts to include things like `margin`, `position`, etc. (Perhaps it uses `rotate` as well to calculate `position`). Therefore, instead of `position`, use `+=number`. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.redSquare').on('click', function() {
        $('.redSquare').css('top', "+=5");
        $('.redSquare').css('left', "+=5");
    });
});
```

This works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/KyD7x/

Comment: This works because the original code was errored, as `.css('top')` and `.position().top` are not the same thing. `.css('top')` gives the 'un-rotated' distance, and `.position().top` gives the rotated distance.

Answer (score 1):

Updated your code for the expected behavior. Please refer this [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tAhar)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.redSquare').on('click', function() {
    $('.redSquare').css('top', parseInt($('.redSquare').css('top')) + 5 + 'px');
        $('.redSquare').css('left', parseInt($('.redSquare').css('left')) + 5 + 'px');
    });
});
```